# Realm Query to variable and results

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, realm

With the following code I'm currently trying to search to my realm db if the `id` `eventId1` is somewhere inside the database in the column `realmeventID` and if it is to print true. But with I get no result even if the statement I know is true!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let realm = try! Realm()
    var tanDogs = realm.objects(eventsNewSaved2.self)
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "realmeventID == %@", eventId1)

    if predicate == true {
        print("true")
    }
}
```

Am I missing something important here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query using `NSPredicate`, you can do the following:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "realmeventID == %@", eventId1)
let results = realm.objects(eventsNewSaved2.self).filter(predicate)
```

This can also be written as follows more easily.

```
let results = realm.objects(eventsNewSaved2.self).filter("realmeventID == %@", eventId1)
```

Whether the result is present you can see in the following manner.

```
if !results.isEmpty {
    // The results is not empty
}
```

or,

```
if let event = results.first {
    // The results is not empty because there is a first element
}
```

So, is the following code you would like to?

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let results = realm.objects(ToDoList.self).filter("realmeventID == %@", eventId1)

if !results.isEmpty {
    print("true")
}
```

Comment: You seem to be familiar with realm! Thanks again!